# Elementary school reader, late 1960s, story with no wheeled vehicles

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Seeking a couple of short stories I read in elementary school in the late 1960s in a magazine (Junior Scholastic, Weekly Reader?). One of the stories came with an illustration "Urban Man" prognosticating life in the future. The other story deals with a future in which there are no wheeled conveyances only hover vehicles. The magazines were in pamphlet form as I remember.

Comment: I remember those magazines.... I think they (or similar ones later) we called "Read" magazines. I seem to remember that title in big letters.  Googled... Looks like "Weekly Reader" was aimed at Kindergarten & Elementary, and "Read" for grade 6-10.